# Why this code update every 13 second?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Just experimenting with measuring distances via geolocation, the script auto update every 13 seconds on my Galaxy s3
I wonder what part of the script trigger that timing for update, how to make it update quicker like every second .

```
window.onload = function () {
    var startPos;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            startPos = position;
            document.getElementById("startLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("startLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Error occurred. Error code: " + error.code);
            // error.code can be:
            //   0: unknown error
            //   1: permission denied
            //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
            //   3: timed out
        });

        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
            document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = calculateDistance(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude,
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
    }
};

// Reused code - copyright Moveable Type Scripts - retrieved May 4, 2010.
// http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
// Under Creative Commons License http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}
Number.prototype.toRad = function () {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

[View The whole code here](http://codepen.io/adamrifai/pen/jPqqXZ)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the current API. See [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)

> The Geolocation.watchPosition() method is used to register a handler function that will be **called automatically each time the position of the device changes**. You can also, optionally, specify an error handling callback function.

emphasis is mine.

You do not need to poll the the location every second, it should notify you when the location has changed automatically.

You should also be able to enable `highAccuracy` mode to give you the best possible results:

```
options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
};

id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tested the code in a moving car, but I noticed the 13 min delay